# VirtualBox: grain table inconsistency

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox

The setup in question is as follows: Windows 7 64bit host running VirtualBox. The guest machine is running Windows XP 32bit.

After a power failure on the host box, the guest machine cannot boot and complains that

> inconsistency between grain table and backup grain table

Any help to boot the guest machine without reinstalling it appreciated.

PS: What is a grain table anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't really help, but I found what the grain tables are here:
http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/VirtualDiskAPIprogramming.pdf (page 16)

Like the user mailq says, looks like your virtual drive is broken. Maybe check the vmdkck tool (on this page http://datto.org/projects/vmdk-tools ) to double check it's broken?

Comment: Thank you too. I accepted your answer because it provided links to locate what a grain table actually is. One can request the virtual disk format specification here http://www.vmware.com/technical-resources/interfaces/vmdk.html

Answer (score 13):

VMware has a tool called `vmware-vdiskmanager` located in `"/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/"` and symlinked to `/usr/local/bin` when installed. **You can use this tool to repair VirtualBox VMDK disks as well**. It saved me a couple of times already.

### Installation

a. You can install [vmware-fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html) (requires macOS Catalina; use `vmware-fusion10` for older macOS versions)

```
brew install vmware-fusion
```

b. Or you can download the `vmware-vdiskmanager` utility directly from *Attachments* section at the bottom of this page:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023856

### Usage

```
vmware-vdiskmanager -R <your_disk>.vmdk
```

Invoking without parameters gives help usage:

```
Usage: vmware-vdiskmanager OPTIONS <disk-name> | <mount-point>
Offline disk manipulation utility
...
     -R                   : check a sparse virtual disk for consistency and attempt
                            to repair any errors.
...
```

Comment: The name of the tool has a v in it: "vmware-vdiskmanager".  I tried to edit the answer, but it only added 2 characters, and edits have to be at least 6? :)

Comment: This worked great, it just saved me after my Mac crashed and left a vagrant virtualbox in a dirty state. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting "no errors were found on the virtual disk" after running the repair command even though I have the same grain table error. Any other ideas fro solving this?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Was able to fix corrupted appliance file (*.vmdk) after forced poweroff.

Comment: I moved my vms from Linux to MacOs, updated Ids and all of my VMs does the same error. I'm always getting the _inconsistency between grain table and backup grain table_. I tried the tool, but it outputs _The virtual disk, '/path/to/virtualbox_disk.vmdk', is corrupted and cannot be repaired._.

Comment: Last night, a ServerFault answer saved my life!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. To give more insight VirtualBox prefers VDI files and has a `vbox-img repair` option but doesn't have extensive functionality for VMDK files which is what VMWare prefers hence why their tool has the better ability to fix issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your virtual hard drive is broken. Grain tables are some internal stuff of virtualization environments.

Googling for the exact term reveals that there are not many possibilities to recover:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=40049

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I had googled prior to asking at SF. I asked hoping for a long-shot answer not already covered by the VirtualBox fora.

Answer (score 2):

I used [CloneVDI](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=22422) to solve this problem. I made a clone and the new file works very well.

Comment: I can attest to this. This saved my life. Whew.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error after moving my `~/VirtualBox\ VMs` from Linux to MacOS. I tried [@mens solution using `vmware-vdiskmanager`](https://serverfault.com/a/575058/191935), but it failed for me.

During my migration from linux to MacOS, I added all of the `*.vbox` files back into Virtualbox and they all failed to boot with the same error (using vagrant):

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "<UUID 1>", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Could not open the medium '/path/to/box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: inconsistency between grain table and backup grain table in '/path/to/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).
VBoxManage: error: VD: error VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER opening image file '/path/to/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
```

I verified that the data transfered correctly, `md5 box-disk1.vmdk` returned the same thing for both files.

I managed to get a vm to boot again by **converting the `vmdk` files to `vdi`** doing the following. (Requires `qemu`, `brew install qemu`)

```
# Convert from `.vmdk` to `.bin`
qemu-img convert box-disk1.vmdk box-disk1.bin

# Convert from `.bin` to `.vdi`
VBoxManage convertdd box-disk1.bin box-disk1.vdi
```

Updated path to volume for `.vdi` and machine booted.

In my case, vdi file is slightly larger, don't forget to delete `.bin` as it's huge. Oh and it fails to authenticate on first run. Anyway, if possible, maybe you should spin up a new vm from scratch instead.